# Application.WorkbookOpen event ( Sap business One )

Tags: excel, vba, events, handler

I want that the Workbook Event Handler( Application.WorkbookOpen event (   ) ) will be activated only when excel is called by SAP BUSINESS ONE  ?
How can I  do it ?
Thanks

Dov

Answer (score 0):

The `WorkbookOpen` will always trigger no matter how you opened the file.

The only way to get around this is to write another Excel file that works as a launcher for your workbook and prevents running events:

Create a new Excel file `MyLauncher.xlsm` and add a `WorkbookOpen` event with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\yourpath\yourfile.xlsm"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

If you now open `MyLauncher.xlsm` it will launch your file without running the `WorkbookOpen` event.

But for anyone who opens the original file `yourfile.xlsm` the `WorkbookOpen` event will run.